# Setting up Zend Debugger

Tags: zend-debugger

I try to configure zend debugger to debug php pages on my local apache server. I followed all instructions from the official forum (http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=962#p4313) but I fail to see the Zend Debugger listed by phpinfo(), after I restart Apache. My php ini is this:

```
zend_extension_ts="C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\Zend\php-5.3.2\5_3_x_nts_comp\ZendDebugger.dll"
zend_debugger.allow_hosts=192.168.0.104/32,127.0.0.1/32
zend_debugger.expose_remotely=always
```

The path to ZendDebugger.dll is correct. I'm using windows 7, 64 bit. There arent any error messages in the apache log or in windows application log.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Thread-Safe version of PHP. Check Zend Extension Build, PHP Extension Build in php info file. If you are using Thread-safe version, you cannot use Non-Thread-Safe version of ZendDebugger.dll. Currently no ZendDebugger.dll is out there for threadsafe PHP 5.3.0.

-Aryan