# Zend debugger working on Apache server on Windows XAMMP

Tags: apache, debugging, zend-framework, xampp

I am having trouble getting Zend debugger working on Apache server on Windows XAMMP installation
- PHP V 5.3.8

here is what I did so far:

1. downloaded & installed Zend Eclipse PDT (PDT 3.0.2 w/Eclipse Indigo) here:
   http://www.zend.com/community/pdt/downloads
2. Downloaded zip file ZendDebugger-20110410-cygwin_nt-i386 from Zend site
3. copied file ZendDebugger-20110410-cygwin_nt-i386\5_3_x_nts_comp\ZendDebugger.dll
   as C:\xampp\php\ext\ZendDebugger.dll
4. found correct php.ini and added these lines to php.ini

   zend_extension_manager.debug_server=/xampp/php/ext/ZendDebugger.dll

   zend_debugger.allow_hosts=127.0.0.1

   zend_debugger.expose_remotely=always
5. re-started apache
6. ran script with phpinfo();
7. looked for reference to debugger in box with line This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine
8. reference not found

Answer (score 1):

Had A similar issue a few days back and what I learnt was that

YOU CANNOT RUN ZEND DEBUGGER WITH PHP 5.3 WITH THREAD SAFETY on a windows system.

(Would have given you the references but I had it on a different system so don't have the history, will update it if I get the links)

The Following are the alternatives you can try:

1.Go back to a 5.2.xx version of php(if that is not a problem) and configure zend debugger for that version.

2.Install Zend server(I've heard that using it makes things a less of a hassle)

3.Use a non-thread safe version of php 5.3(not sure but It may work)

4.Don't use zend_debugger, use an alternative like Xdebug instead, (I am using it currently and it works fine).

Update:
Got these for links for you.

[Is it still true that zenddebugger only supports non-thread-safe PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948321/is-it-still-true-that-zenddebugger-only-supports-non-thread-safe-php)

http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=1918#p13729

[Setting up Zend Debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491687/setting-up-zend-debugger)

Hope they help